# C#: Add and HTTP method in AWS without configuring API Gateway. Is this a valid approach?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, http, lambda

I've been working with AWS Lambda in C# a bit, and I need to create an HTTP endpoint inside of lambda. The lambda is currently triggered by cloudwatch, and I need to add an HTTP endpoint for an additional task, so I was wondering what's the most simple way to add an HTTP endpoint to AWS lambda? I found this solution, which seems to be okay, but what do you think? Maybe you have worked with it and found some great solutions? Thank you for your time.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("RouteToHandler")]        
public APIGatewayProxyResponse RequestHandler(ILambdaContext context)
{
    var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
    {
        StatusCode = 200,
        Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("something")                
    };

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Use Lambda function URLs. Check the step 5 here - https://coderjony.com/blogs/building-a-serverless-aspnet-core-web-api-with-aws-lambda-using-function-urls

Comment: @AnkushJain The OP's question is regarding an extra endpoint *within* their Lambda.

Comment: Yes that's fine but it really depends on how many routes you will have etc.

Comment: Thank you.
Any other things I should configure? I added the event ("event": "Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayProxyRequest") in aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json 
Is there anything else I should consider for the endpoint to work?